# How to add HTTP Headers to Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins, http-headers, crlf-vulnerability

I run the latest jenkins as a standalone as below.

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

We used self-signed SSL certificate. When we access the Jenkins console and observe the HTTP response headers we see critical HTTP headers missing like for example `X-XSS-Protection`

We do not use or plan to use any web proxy but like to access the Jenkins URL directly https://localhost:9043

I already read this article but it does not seem to have any solution: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24548

Can you please suggest how can i add the `X-XSS-Protection` for say to my Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not name `X-XSS-Protection` critical. I would name it pretend-you-do-something.

Having said that, there's a plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-security-settings/

In the article you will also read:

> For more complex header rewrite rules, using a reverse proxy such as
> Apache with mod_headers is a more complete solution.